# Is there a way to reduce the following code to two lines in python (one line for x and the other one for y)?

Tags: python

```
x=np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
y=[]
for i in x:
    for j in i:
        y.append((i, j))
```

The best I could do to get `y` in one-line python code is to define a 2d array and then flatten it

```
y=np.ravel([[(i, j) for j in i] for i in x])
```

Is there better way to define `y`?

Comment: You have it in one line, but you want it in two lines? Why?

Comment: I think they want a oneline which is clearer and/or more efficient

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. The `two lines` in title was supposed to mean one line for x and the other one for y

Comment: Can you show what your expected result is? Can you not just use `y = itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)`?

Comment: My initial intention was to obtain a list of pairs from a 2d array `x` so that I can use it to initialize a dictionary. The above code is just a simplified example, I know the `i` and `j` doesn't make some material sense here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the 2d list.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

x = np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))
y = chain.from_iterable(x)
```

Now `x` looks like

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
```

and `y` (when iterated or converted to list) looks like

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

The `chain` function is really just undoing the `reshape`. So why not leave it out?